How to subscribe to rosbridge messages in Postman for debugging
I have set-up the Rosbridge Server to broadcast ROS messages via websocket, following these instructions.
I've confirmed that the messages are indeed getting sent by creating the following Python script which subscribes to the /my_topic topic, and writes it to the console:
from __future__ import print_function
import roslibpy

client = roslibpy.Ros(host='localhost', port=9090)
client.run()

listener = roslibpy.Topic(client, '/my_topic', 'topic/type')
listener.subscribe(lambda message: print(message))

try:
    while True:
        pass
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    client.terminate()

However, I want to be able to use Postman to see messages while developing. What do I need to "send" from Postman in order for it to subscribe to a topic in the same way that roslibpy.Topic.subscribe works? Postman supports websockets, and I was able to connect to the Rosbridge server by pointing it to 127.0.0.1:9090, but I need to understand what the client needs to do to subscribe to a topic. Ultimately I'll be using roslibjs with a web application, but for debugging, I'd like to use Postman.

btw, I don't recommend ros-bridge + roslibjs any longer. We've built Transitive to overcome some of its shortcomings: https://transitiverobotics.com/docs/learn/intro/

@ChristianFritz that's interesting - I'll look into Transitive. Although it looks like a much bigger change for my need at this point.

If you want something quick that "just works", you can check out the ROS Tool capability: https://transitiverobotics.com/caps/transitive-robotics/ros-tool/. That gives you a lot of the features of using the open-source directly without any setup.

You would need to send a subscription command the way the rosbridge protocol specifies it. You could read the roslibjs code for that but I think there is an easier way: just add some boiler plate roslibjs code to your page, subscribe using that, and then look at the WS tab in the dev console's network tab. There you'll see the actual WS exchange. Once you have that you can send those same messages in Postman.
PS: The protocol seems to be pretty simple though (from https://wiki.ros.org/rosbridge_suite):
{ "op": "subscribe",
  "topic": "/cmd_vel",
  "type": "geometry_msgs/Twist"
}

Seems like that would be all you'd need to send (updated with your topic of course).
